# Firebase не записывает данные, почему?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Firebase почему то не записывает данные, вчера делал похожее приложение, через поля данные записываются в fb db. Сейчас - нет, пробовал пересоздавать проект полностью с нуля - безрезультатно.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        Button loginBtn;
        Button orderBtn;
        EditText nameTrack;
        EditText phoneTrack;
        EditText nameOrder;
        EditText phoneOrder;
        EditText addressOrder;
        private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
        private String USER_KEY = "User";
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
            orderBtn = findViewById(R.id.makeAnOrderButton);
            nameTrack = findViewById(R.id.trackName);
            phoneTrack = findViewById(R.id.trackPhone);
            nameOrder = findViewById(R.id.orderName);
            phoneOrder = findViewById(R.id.orderPhone);
            addressOrder = findViewById(R.id.orderAddress);
            mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
        }
    
        public void gotToOrderActivity(View view) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
            CustomerModel customerModel = new CustomerModel(0, nameOrder.getText().toString(), phoneOrder.getText().toString(), addressOrder.getText().toString());
            myRef.setValue(customerModel);
    
            if (nameOrder.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || phoneOrder.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || addressOrder.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fill up all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userName", nameOrder.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("userPhone", phoneOrder.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("userAddress", addressOrder.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
        public void trackOrder(View view) {
            if(nameTrack.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || phoneTrack.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fill up all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421172/basic-firebase-database-save

Comment: Попробуйте рекомендации из данного поста, а потом будем разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Создал новый проект, все скопировал - заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не записываються данные так как вы изменили сервер вручную. и нужно указать ссылку базы данных в методе getInstance("url");